# Storing Array Of String in Queue in C# AsynC

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s45n6.png)I am reading from MySql DB using C# but because I am doing some fata processing for the data which is coming out from DB so I had to store these data in order using  Queue<> Class.
I am trying to store the data as ( String[] arr ) format in the Queue

but I found the Queue memory is ecpanding per each time storing data but the last group of array data will be repeated in side queue memory which I believe I am doing something wrong.
I believe it is clear in the attached image.

Notices:
I am calling Queue.Enqueue(arr) method inside another Async method which I believe it is very problematic way as in below

`

```
 public async void DBReadAsync(Calculations.RetStartEndDates f, DataBufferCls.DataBuffer dt)
        {
            int i;
            Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                 DB.ReadFromDB3(f, dt);


            }

            ) ;
            await t1;

        }
```

public string[] ReadFromDB3(RetStartEndDates WeekStrtEnd, DataBuffer dt)
{

```
        string s;
        string[] arr = new string[8];

        string fromtime = WeekStrtEnd.StartTime_Str;/// "8:40:30";"10:09:00";  //
        string FromDate = WeekStrtEnd.StartDateDBFormate_Str; //"2022-10-14 "; //"2022-11-06 "; //
        string FromTD = FromDate + " " + fromtime;

        string Totime = WeekStrtEnd.EndTime_Str; //"11:19:22";  //
        string ToDate = WeekStrtEnd.EndDateDBFormate_Str; //"2022-11-07 "; //
        string ToTD = ToDate + " " + Totime;


        Console.WriteLine($"Start date is {FromTD}");
        Console.WriteLine($"End Date is {ToTD}");
        string query = "SELECT * FROM data_46";  

        //Open connection
        if (this.IsConnect())
        {
            StartReadingFromDB_Event("Hold");
            dt.Monitortest();

            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, Connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                arr[0] = dataReader[0].ToString();
                arr[1] = dataReader[1].ToString();
                arr[2] = dataReader[2].ToString();
                arr[3] = dataReader[3].ToString();
                arr[4] = dataReader[4].ToString();
                arr[5] = dataReader[5].ToString();
                arr[6] = dataReader[6].ToString();
                arr[7] = dataReader[7].ToString();

                dt.WrToBuffer3(arr);
                Thread.Sleep(10);

            }[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAJnB.png)`
```

```
`
```

`

I am trying to understand the reason for that

Comment: I am sorry in advance if I could not be able to explain my problem perfectly

Comment: Please start by posting valid code - the `ReadFromDB3` method is clearly incomplete

Comment: The code is too long and messy to be honest for that reason I was trying to send some related piece of codes which is related to the problem

Comment: The `Queue.Enqueue()` can accept an object as a parameter, so it should work. Other than that and to keep things simple, why don't you concatenate the array of strings with a specific separator and store the resulting joined string in the queue? When you dequeue that value, you split it using the same separator.

Comment: I totally agreed with you but I believe the problem not in the parameter data type, so what is happening with the array it will happen with the string because the Queue.Enqueue() it seems like when It has been called inside Async method this will adding more slot in the memory area of the queue but data will fill all of these areas , I don’t know how can I describe that